# mingw-w64 cannot link to boost

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, ubuntu-14.04, mingw-w64

I have installed `g++-mingw-w64-i686` to compile a `c++11` application for windows on linux:

```
sudo apt-get install g++-mingw-w64-i686
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev-i386
```

I am wondering why it cannot link to boost

main7.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"Hello world!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

compiling:

```
$ i686-w64-mingw32-g++ main7.cpp -Wfatal-errors -o main -std=c++11 -I'/usr/include/c++/4.9' -L'/usr/lib' -L'/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/lib' -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lboost_serialization -pthread
```

Result:

```
/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lboost_system
/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lboost_thread
/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lboost_serialization
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

While `gcc` works:

```
g++ main7.cpp -Wfatal-errors -o main -std=c++11 -I'/usr/include/c++/4.9' -L'/usr/lib'  -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lboost_serialization -pthread
```

---

```
$ g++ --version
```

> g++ (Ubuntu 4.9.3-8ubuntu2~14.04) 4.9.3

Comment: It sounds like you haven't installed the windows boost libs, you can't link your native Linux libs to windows objects.

Comment: @user657267 How to specify boost to install in windows lib format?

Comment: I don't know, search the apt-get package list.

Comment: @user657267 any idea what to search?

Comment: I had a quick search on Ubuntu's package page but couldn't find anything, you may need to cross compile the boost libs yourself.

Comment: @ar2015 This is not really related to programming. You should find necessary library dependencies somehow. The good start will be to search for "boost mingw". Ubuntu default repos do not provide boost libraries for mingw. You could build them yourself or to just choose [a linux distribution which is not made for bored housewives](http://pastebin.com/y2u6qFcw) (joke ;) ).

Answer (score -1):

You need to cross-compile from source the Boost libraries that you want to link to.
Ubtuntu does not package Windows versions of the Boost libraries. Boost.org distributes pre-built Windows binaries on Sourceforge,
but they are built for MSVC++ only, hence are not binary-compatible with mingw-w64.

To cross-compile the boost libraries, I suggest you consult:

- [Boost: getting started](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html)

especially:

- [Easy build and install](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#easy-build-and-install)

and:

- [Cross compilation](http://www.boost.org/build/doc/html/bbv2/tasks/crosscompile.html)

and:

- [Ubuntu: How to install boost from source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1180792)

I have not done this myself, so cannot speak as to any snags you may encounter.

Some other linux distributions package mingw boost binaries, e.g.

- [ArchLinux](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/mingw-w64-boost/)
- [Fedora](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/mingw-boost)

If there is some reason why you cannot build your program on Windows in one
of the unix-like environments (cygwin,MYSYS2) or cross-compiling
boost proves too hard, then you might consider cross-compiling your program in a Fedora/ArchLinux VM.